# How to achieve animation effects

Tags: javascript, css

In this [website](https://pizza.az/az/), the header is animated when you scroll the page a bit. Can you please advise what techniques, tools and best practices (broadly) one may use to achieve this and similar effects?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to add a class to the header element when the scroll position is at the top (bind to the onscroll event and check if at the top or not).
Then define new postiions for your elements in css when that class is applied, and use the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) css property to animate it

Comment: thanks. i'll go learn transitions

Answer (score 1):

Well for the animation occurring when you scroll you would use

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
 if($(document).scrollTop() === 0);

} else {

});
```

As for the animation, there are many ways to do this and the question is too broad, as stated above.

Comment: thank you. I just want to get some directions in which i can research. It looks very difficult for me to create smth like this

Comment: It's not too hard but animation is very time-consuming

Answer (score 1):

the way I personally do it, is to add a class to the body on scroll. I then style the particular element I want to change (in your case the header) accordingly. I add it to the body instead of the particular element in case I want to manipulate other selectors, etc.

This is the JS I use:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 50) { //distance scrolled before effect takes place
     jQuery("body").addClass("scrolled");
  } else {
     jQuery("body").removeClass("scrolled");
  }
});
```

Then I'd add some CSS for example:

```
header{height:100px;transition:all, .4s, ease; /*Make sure to use all cross-browser markup*/;}
body.scrolled header{height:50px;}
```